# How to make an Arc welder out of 3500v bug zapper transformer?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, arc

I got a transformer from old bug zapper it has 3500v output [image: transformer picture] , can I use it to make an Arc welder by removing the secondary windings and put 10 gauge wire windings instead.
I saw some videos on youtube to make it using microwave transformer, can I use the same concept?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your looking in the wrong direction a bug zapper produces voltage, arc wielding needs lots of current (from a low impedance source).

Comment: @laptop2d - the poster did say they were going to replace the secondary with a new one, and described one wound for lower voltage and higher current.  However it would probably still be weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned replacing the secondary with 10-gauge wire - I'm guessing that you have some understanding of the thicker wire's greater current-carrying capacity, which you would need for an arc welder.

The problem here is that the magnetic core - the steel laminations - also have a maximum magnetic flux carrying capacity, just like the wire has a maximum current-carrying capacity. The bug-zapper manufacturer would have used the lowest-cost (smallest) laminated core that met the power needs of the zapper - which are MUCH less than what you'll need for an arc welder. You would find that the secondary current would max out at a too-low value.

One caution - if you do get hold of a microwave transformer, DO NOT power it up on the bench top. Microwave transformers are one of the few devices that supply both high voltage and relatively high current - and are pretty much guaranteed to kill you if you get across the HV side.  Not sure about bug zappers, but I'd be very cautious with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

No real way of knowing without having specific specifications for the transformer.

Be aware that an ARC welder works with high current and low voltage. On the other hand the 10awg wire you propose is generally considered to be  good for 30A carrying capacity and that may limit performance. Most welding rigs go up to several hundred amps.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer you show, going by the size of the connecting wires and of the transformer itself, could not handle enough power (V x A, approximately), to weld anything thicker than metal foil.

However, it might have enough voltage to make a very small [Jacob's ladder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hhaaSSCU5k) display. In air at STP, a spark between rounded wires can jump ~1 mm/1,000 volts, so the separation between wires at the bottom should be ~3mm. Because the ballast inductor limits current, it should be safe to operate the ladder for a minute at a time, allowing the transformer to cool between uses.

Safety notes:

- Put the arc in a ventilated enclosure.
- Make sure the transformer and base of the enclosure is grounded.